# send multiple JSON objects via Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to send multiple JSON objects via Ajax.

My objects (created from multiple forms) are below;

When the Ajax sends the JSON its empty. however if i search any one of the json object it contains values. i think the problem seems to be when i create multi layer objects.

I also need to understand how i can access the objects in my controller.

Would it be somthing like: `data.dataFormOne.title`.

```
var dataFormOne   = ''; 
var dataFormTwo   = '';
var dataFormThree = '';

$("#formone").submit(function(e){
  var title   = $('select[name="Title"]').val();    
  dataFormOne = {firstname: firstname};
});                 

$("#formtwo").submit(function(e){
  var address = $("#address").val();;    
  dataFormTwo = {address: address};
});                                  

$("#formtwo").submit(function(e){
  var country   = $("#country").val();; 
  dataFormThree = {country: country};
});                          

function sendData() {
  var data = {
    formone:   dataFormOne,
    formtwo:   dataFormTwo, 
    formThree: dataFormThree,
  }; 

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:URL,
    dataType: "json",
    data: data ,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) { 
      if (data.result) {
        console.log(data.result);
      } else {
        alert("There has been an error\nPlease make sure you are logged in.");
      }
    },
    complete: function () {}
  });                   
}
```

Comment: 1. You have two `#formtwo` in the code.. Shouldn't it be one? 2. In the submit callback function, are you calling the `sendData` function?

Answer (score -1):

set traditional to true in your ajax configuration
and send it like this

```
 traditional : true,
 data:{formone: dataFormOne,formtwo: dataFormTwo,formThree: dataFormThree}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've created an example code from your question. There are a few things you were missing (like not calling sendData on each submit), also multiple forms on a single page are not "permitted" (you can still use it though, just pointing that out). Also the data object was reformatted. Once you receive that object on your controller you will be easily able to search for the fields you need.

Once you run this example take a look at the console for an example of what will be posted back to your controller (you need to uncomment the ajax post back call to make it work)

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/wfkggtzm/1/

var dataFormOne = ''; 
 var dataFormTwo ='';
var dataFormThree ='';

```
 $("#formone").submit(function(e){
             dataFormOne     = {firstname: firstname};
             sendData(e);
         });                 

            $("#formtwo").submit(function(e){
             var address = $("#address").val();;    
                                console.log($("#formtwo").serialize());
             dataFormTwo     = {address: address};
             sendData(e);
         });                                  

           $("#formtwo").submit(function(e){
             var country = $("#country").val();;    
             dataFormThree     = {country: country};
             sendData(e);
         });                          



        function sendData(e) {

          var  data     = {dataFormOne,
                          dataFormTwo, 
                          dataFormThree,
                          }; 
                    console.dir(data);
        e.preventDefault();
        /*
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:URL,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: data ,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data)
                    { 
                        if (data.result)
                        {
                         console.log(data.result);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("There has been an error\nPlease make sure you are logged in.");
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function () {}
                });                   

                */
}
```